# ASP.Net Web API Controller Unit Test POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am new to Unit Testing and am trying to create some Xunit tests for my Web API Controller's `POST` method.

Here is my Controller's `POST` method:

```
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateArea([FromBody] AreaForCreationDto area)
{
    // Check that the 'area' object parameter can be de-serialised to a AreaForCreationDto.
    if (area == null)
    {
        var message = "Could not de-serialise the request body to an AreaForCreationDto object";
        _logger.LogError(message);

        // Return an error 400.
        return BadRequest(message);
    }

    /*
     * ModelState.IsValid is determined by the attributes associated with the 
     * Data Annotations on the properties of the ViewModel.
     */
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Return a response with a Status Code 422.
        return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(ModelState);
    };

    // Map a AreaForCreationDto object to a Area entity.
    var areaEntityToAdd = _mapper.Map<Area>(area);

    // Call the repository to add the new Area entity to the DbContext.
    _areaRepository.AddArea(areaEntityToAdd);

    // Save the new Area entity, added to the DbContext, to the SQL database.
    if (await _areaRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
    {
        // Note: AutoMapper maps the values of the properties from the areaEntityToAdd
        // to a new areaToReturn object.
        // This ensures that we don't expose our Area entity to the web browser.
        var areaToReturn = _mapper.Map<AreaDto>(areaEntityToAdd);

        // Return a 201 'created' response along with the location URL in the
        // response Header.
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetArea",
            new { id = areaToReturn.Id },
            areaToReturn);
    }
    else {
        // The save failed.
        var message = $"Could not save new Area {areaEntityToAdd.Id} to the database.";
        _logger.LogWarning(message);
        throw new Exception(message);
    };
}
```

The first Unit Test I have written is intended to ensure that on sending a POST request, with an object which can be de-serialised into an `AreaForCreation` object, the function returns a `201 CreatedAtRouteResult` along with the new Area which has been created.

Here is the Xunit test:

```
[Fact]
public void ReturnAreaForCreateArea()
{
    //Arrange

    var _mockAreaRepository = new Mock<IAreaRepository>();
    _mockAreaRepository
        .Setup(x => x.AddArea(testArea));

    var _mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    _mockMapper
        .Setup(_ => _.Map<Area>(It.IsAny<AreaForCreationDto>()))
        .Returns(testArea);

    var _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<AreasController>>();
    var _sut = new AreasController(_mockAreaRepository.Object, _mockLogger.Object, _mockMapper.Object);

    // Act
    var result = _sut.CreateArea(testAreaForCreationDto);

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    var objectResult = Assert.IsType<CreatedAtRouteResult>(result);
    var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<AreaDto>(objectResult.Value);
    var areaDescription = model.Description;
    Assert.Equal("Test Area For Creation", areaDescription);
}
```

I am getting an exception thrown when the unit test tries to `Assert.IsType<CreatedAtRouteResult>(result)`. Debugging revealed that the Controller was failing to save to the repository. My `AreaRepository` has the following AddArea function which does not return a value so I assume that my `_mockAreaRepository` does not require a `Return` condition set (could be wrong here).

Do I need to configure my `mockAreasRepository` for the outcome of calling `SaveChangesAsync()`?

Comment: Yes because it is async you need to mock the return of a completed task to allow the method to be able to continue. You also need to update the test to be async as well by return a `Task` and await the method under test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because it is async you need to mock the return of a completed task to allow the method

```
await _areaRepository.SaveChangesAsync()
```

to be able to continue.

You also need to update the test to be *async* as well by returning a `Task` and *await* the method under test.

```
[Fact]
public async Task ReturnAreaForCreateArea() { //<-- note test is now async as well
    //Arrange

    var _mockAreaRepository = new Mock<IAreaRepository>();
    _mockAreaRepository
        .Setup(x => x.AddArea(testArea));

    _mockAreaRepository
        .Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(true); //<-- returns completed Task<bool> when invoked

    var _mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    _mockMapper
        .Setup(_ => _.Map<Area>(It.IsAny<AreaForCreationDto>()))
        .Returns(testArea);
    _mockMapper
        .Setup(_ => _.Map<AreaDto>(It.IsAny<Area>()))
        .Returns(testAreaDto);

    var _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<AreasController>>();
    var _sut = new AreasController(_mockAreaRepository.Object, _mockLogger.Object, _mockMapper.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await _sut.CreateArea(testAreaForCreationDto);//<-- await 

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    var objectResult = Assert.IsType<CreatedAtRouteResult>(result);
    var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<AreaDto>(objectResult.Value);
    var areaDescription = model.Description;
    Assert.Equal("Test Area For Creation", areaDescription);
}
```

Comment: Long delay as I was diverted onto another project. We finally tried your very helpful advise but the very first Assertion (.NotNull) failed. The Controller saves the newly created `Area` entity to the Repository and then returns an `Area` which is created by calling the function at the `GetArea` route, passing in the new `Id`. Do I need to configure the `GetArea` function of the Controller in order for this to work?

Comment: Then something has changed in your code from what you showed originally. The logic in your code does not allow for the returning of *null*.

Comment: True, our controller is only returning a `CreatedAtRoute` if the `SaveChangesAsync()` is successful, if it fails we have not provided for the return of a `Error Code 500` so that we should never have `null` returned. I will continue to try and see what is going wrong during the save.

Comment: If my `await _areaRepository.SaveChangesAsync()` returns `true`, then my controller under test maps an `AreaEntityToAdd` to an `AreaDTO` and passes this in to the `GetArea` method of the controller along with the new `Area`s id. I haven't accounted for the mapping and repository actions within the `GetArea` function in my `_mockMapper` and `_mockRepository`. Do I need to?

Comment: Yes for the mapping

Comment: Perfect, that was it. Have you ever written a blog or know of a good resource for unit testing controllers please? As you can see, I find it difficult and cannot find a good source of reference.

Comment: There is way too much to narrow them down. I just googled `unit testing controllers asp.net` and a list of resources, articles and official documentation came up. You can also find a lot on this site as well.